# What is the best approach to follow in WebService developments?

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

Is it starting from WSDL or from coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are asking is what is better: bottom up (coding first) vs top down (wsdl first).

There are many, many articles on the topic, so you can do a quick google search. [This](http://oracled.wordpress.com/2009/12/25/developing-web-service-top-down-vs-bottom-up-approach/) looks like a good article I found by searching.

Answer (score 0):

It is depends on requirement and feasibilty.But mostly in case of service provider,first we write the code then generate the wsdl and publish it..When consumer wants to consumes the service then ,they generate the client code from wsdl and invoke the services....That how most application works......